# Reinstalled Ubuntu on a new drive, formatted & removed old drive - now coming to emergency mode

Tags: boot, disk-formatting

I installed a new NVMe drive, and used a LiveUSB to format & install Ubuntu 22.04 onto it. I then formatted the old drive Ubuntu was on and removed it from the computer.

Whenever I boot now, I get dumped into 'emergency mode' after GRUB. What went wrong and how can I fix it?

The emergency mode is hard to use as well since it only shows up on the 2nd vertical half of the screen, so half of what it shows at the bottom is off the screen.

Comment: From what you are describing you've formatted everything so there's nothing important to recover and it would just be easier/quicker to format everything again and do a fresh install. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did it work ok, before you removed old drive? When you installed to new NVMe drive was part installed to old drive? What brand/model system? What video card chip? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: It worked before I removed the old drive. Not sure what you mean about a part. System is AMD Ryzen 5 3600 / Gigabyte X570 Aorus Elite / Gigabyte GeForce RTX 4080 AERO OC 16G. Where do I get the BootInfo summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EFI boot partition was missing, reinstalling with it included worked.

Comment: It was likely the ESP (EFI system partition) was placed on the old-drive which was in the machine when you installed. The person who installed Lubuntu should have realized that, as that detail is shown & verified (prior to install commencing) during the install process. Your *firmware* config will influence which drive `calamares` selects for this where there are multiple drives where it can be installed.

Comment: I did not mention Lubuntu nor calamares at all... is this a chatgpt-provided answer?

Comment: Sorry, I must have been distracted, as you didn't specify what 22.04 product, thus what installer you actually used. `ubiquity` is mostly the same; influenced by how ISO is written to thumb-drive, but acts same on EFI hardware (`ubiquity` differs though on *legacy/CSM* boots to `calamares` install though in that ESP isn't created with `calamares` but is with `ubiquity`). You may have used `subiquity` though as you didn't specify 22.04 product or ISO/installer used (there were 4 ISO/installer choices for 22.04) - sorry I was mistaken.

Comment: If you were using `ubiquity`, you can write the ISO incorrect to thumb-drive which will *trick* the `ubiquity` installer to attempt to write the boot code to the actual thumb-drive itself (which will fail!), however this will **not** happen if the ISO is written correctly using the approved/documented procedures (as confirmed via QA). Alas you didn't specify what ISO/installer, nor how it was written  (*this has been noted on a few releases since & included 20.10 where changes have been made; and how ISO written does matter*)